# Convert integer to timedelta with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a variable,

```
minhold=100
```

This is an int

I want to convert it to be understood as "100 days"

How do I do this?

I am aware of the pd.to_datetime function but cant get it to work.

Basically, I have another variable in my dataframe, which is a time:

```
x=Timedelta('104 days 00:00:00')
```

If I do, x>minhold, I expect True, as 104 days is > 100 days, but it gives an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timedelta' with type 'int64'
```

lastly, if I do:

```
pd.to_timedelta(minhold)
```

This gives me `Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.000000')` which I don't expect. I expected 100 days.

Comment: [read the manual of the function you use?](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) ?  specify D as unit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html#pandas-to-timedelta), specify `unit='D'` (for "days") when calling `to_timedelta`.

```
>>> pd.to_timedelta(100, unit='D')
Timedelta('100 days 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> pd.Timedelta('100D')
>>> Timedelta('100 days 00:00:00')
```

or

```
>>> pd.Timedelta(100, 'D')
>>> Timedelta('100 days 00:00:00')
```

will give you a 100 day time period. I found this out by looking at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html).